# Exiting from javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript function:

```
function displayMessage() {
    var message = $("#msg").val();

    if (message == "") { 
        alert("You need to enter a message");//alert the user
        return false;
    }

    postData = {
        "message": message,
    };    

    ...

}
```

What am hoping this achieves is, if the input field is empty, display the alert and remain in the function.If it isn't then continue.
My submit button is linked to another page but this page is displayed anyways regardless of what happens in the if statement.

This is the form code:

```
<form id="post" action="http://localhost:8080/uploadNewMessage" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="msg" class="input">Message:</label>
            <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" size="10"/>
        </div>
        <a href="profile-page.html" id="submit" data-role="button" data- theme="b">Submit</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the full javascript code just incase:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // 1. The Registration button
    $("#submit").bind('click', function(event) {

        displayMessage();

    });

});

function doPostRequest(postData) {

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        dataType: "json",
        data: postData

    });
}

function displayMessage() {
    var message = $("#msg").val();

    if (message == "") { 
        alert("You need to enter a message");//alert the user
        return false;
    }

    postData = {
        "message": message,
    };    

    ...
    doPostRequest(postData);
}
```

Comment: `action=<...>` what kind of language is this?

Comment: It's my native language. :D Pardon me, let me edit that,i was just trying to leave that part out.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
$("#submit").bind('click', function(event) {
    var message = $.trim($("#msg").val());
    if(!message.length) {
        alert("You need to enter a message");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
        doPostRequest({"message":message});
    }
});
```

Comment: why is the `return false;` needed?

Comment: I have tried this, but somehow i am still being redirected to the profile page

Comment: Then you have other `JS` errors, check for the errors on browser's console and fix them.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu have you tried all the suggested solutions? Have you set the `url: URL,` -> URL ?

Comment: Am trying them all out now.

Answer (score 1):

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/litun/3/edit)**

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
        displayMessage();
    });
});
```

and also:

```
function displayMessage() { 
    var message = $.trim( $("#msg").val() ); // trim whitespaces
    if (message === "") { 
        alert("You need to enter a message");
    }else{                              // Use the else statement
      doPostRequest({
        "message" : message
      });   
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try this with `event.preventDefault()`, the button changes to another color and the message is posted to GAE but the page doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` variable that is passed via your `click` event handler contains a function named `preventDefault`. If you don't want the form to submit, call this (`event.preventDefault()`). This will prevent the submit button from submitting the form.

Comment: Objects are variables too.

Comment: If I create a new object and assign it to a variable, is that variable no longer a variable?